# Setting up OpenGL on Embarcadero's C++-Builder

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, c++builder, borland-c++

I have a Problem Setting up OpenGL with Embarcadero's C++-Builder.
I managed to successfully compile the Project from here
 http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10528
so I can use functions like `glClearColor`, or `glBegin()`, `glVertex3f()` or `glEnd`, but I get unresolved external Errors when I try and use 
`glGenBuffers`, `glBindBuffer`, `glUseProgramm` and so on.

Question: What are the steps to follow to set this up correctly?

I also downloaded Glew from here http://glew.sourceforge.net/.
The binary Version does not work, because as usually you can't use .lib files for Visual Studio with Embarcadero.

So I tried to compile the sources with Embarcadero.
There is a CMakeLists.txt, but when I type
cmake -G "Borland Makefiles" path-to-my-downloaded-sources 
in the Directory where I want my Borland Makefiles, the error message is

Could NOT find PkgConfig.

The sources I downloaded from http://glew.sourceforge.net/ do only contain 3 .c-files, so I created myself a Static-Library Project with Embarcadero and built it. 
Now If I add These test lines to my Project

```
#include <GL\glew.h> 
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
```

and link to that static library, it compiles, but I get a runtime error

Access Violation at adddress ...

Adding the glew32.dll from the bin-Version of GLEW does not help here.

So what should I do? In particular, how do I compile a .dll with Embarcadero, although glew.c from the sources does not contain any __declspec(DLL_EXPORT) Statement?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032386/glgenbuffers-not-defined

Comment: No it's not yet sufficient, although it helped me to not get a linker error any more, but a runtime error. I edited my questions, so you see what I tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up Opengl for Borlandc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146116/setting-up-opengl-for-borlandc)

Comment: start with simple GL only http://stackoverflow.com/a/20679773/2521214 and when working then add GLEW ... GLEW must be initialized only After the GL init !!!