# Generated window with GLFW, background color not changing

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to change the background color in a window generated by OpenGL/GLFW and I'm using a similar code than the one in the GLFW docs. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and the window background is always black, no matter the parameters in the glClearColor() function.

I tried this on Windows 10 using VS and it worked perfectly, but on Ubuntu it's not working at all. No error messages are generated.

I also followed *The Cherno's Sparky* game engine series, and tried encapsulating the glClear() function in a class method, but this didn't change anything.

This is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        // Initialization failed
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        // Window or OpenGL context creation failed
        std::cout << "Error creating window!" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
    {
        int width, height;

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm supposed to get a window with a red background but it's black.

As additional elements, I'm also using CMake to help configuring and building the project (quite overkill I know), and I believe clang is the compiler used for the project. Maybe that influences the result.

Comment: The code looks OK and run properly on Windows with MSVC. So it's probably something specific to your platform.

Comment: Most probably, might be because I'm using old OpenGL functions defined in the headers. I'll update the libraries or get newer ones, see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an appropriate loader after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`.

If you are using glad, you should call `gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress)` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)` as the official doc suggests [here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_context_current).

Comment: I'm not using any OpenGL library like glad or GLEW. The second include (GL/gl.h) was added automatically when I added the OpenGL methods such as glClear and glClearColor. Maybe they're old OpenGL methods. I checked my OpenGL version using glxinfo and it showed version 4.5. Another thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268061/mesa-linux-gl-h-does-not-contain-modern-opengl) mentioned it could be due to those old methods. I'll be adding glad as an OpenGL library and try again.

Comment: I installed and setup GLAD so I'm able to use more recent OpenGL related functions. It now works great!